# Run Python script in background on remote server with Django view

Tags: python, django

What I want to achieve is to run python some script which will collect data and insert it to DB in a background.
So basically, a person opens Django view, clicks on a button and then closes the browser and Django launches this script on a server, the script then collects data in background while everything else goes on its own.

What is the best library, framework, module or package to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is the most used tool for such tasks.

Comment: So about Celery, could I run local broker on same server? If I have for example just one script (task) or just go without broker at all?
I just never tried celery

Comment: we quit using celery for realy complex work. ended up writing our own library, wrapping amazon's boto interface to the simple workflow foundation (swf). if you can not rely on your machines not crashing, and if you have a non-trivial workflow to implement (not just a "simple" parallelization need), celery might not be enough.

Comment: @lwiii Of course you can run worker on the same machine with your web server. To use celery you have to run at least one worker.

Answer (score 2):

Celery is a good suggestion, but its a bit heavy solution and there more simple and straightforward solution exist unless you need full power of celery.

So i suggest to use [rq](https://github.com/nvie/rq) and [django integration of rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq).

RQ inspired by the good parts of Celery, Resque , and has been created as a lightweight alternative to the heaviness of Celery or other AMQP-based queuing implementations.

Comment: Celery has a broker which runs over django orm.  So in case of simple tasks there is no need for AMQP server.  On the other hand rq requires Redis to operate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd humbly reccomend the standard library module `multiprocessing` for this. As long as the background process can run on the same server as the one processing the requests, you'll be fine.

Although i consider this to be the simplest solution, this wouldn't scale well at all, since you'd be running extra processess on your server. If you expect these things to only happen once in a while, and not to last that long, it's a good quick solution.

One thing to keep in mind though: In the newly started process *ALWAYS* close your database connection before doing anything - this is because the forked process shares the same connection to the SQL server and might enter into data races with your main django process.

Comment: Thanks, will also give `multiprocessing` a shot